# How to call a specific character from a string in C++?

Tags: c++

How would I recall, say, the fourth character and output it on the screen from this code?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;


int main () {
    cout << "Enter word: ";
    char random[99];
    cin >> random;
    \\right here is where I would like to output the fourth character of the string "random"
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `cout << random[3] << endl;`

Comment: Seems like a valid question to me.

Comment: thanks. when i was testing this i was using strings that had four characters and forgot that there was a zero value as well

Comment: `cin >> random;` Right there you have a buffer overflow bug. Why aren't you using `std::string`? Get [a good book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)!

Answer (score 4):

```
cout << random[3];
```

Consider reading [a good book on C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: Op does not need the statement he needs an understanding of how arrays work.

Comment: @Captain Giraffe: Exactly, and for that he needs to read a book on C++

Comment: I'm teaching myself C++ using mostly this site and cplusplus.com. Sorry if I ask stupid questions, but it's the only way I'll learn.

Comment: @Redmasti: You will have next to no chance to properly learn C++ without [a good book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: @sbi: Thanks for the advice. I'll definitely try to obtain a good book.